# AngularJS Promise being rejected without waiting for async response (it should resolve)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, promise, angular-routing

In my scenario, when a visitor navigates to a page (or route) of the first time they should be anonymously authenticated (I'm using Firebase). For context; later on the visitor may migrate their anonymous session after they have logged in, with Facebook, for example.

If the anonymous authentication fails for some reason, they are redirected to an error page (route) -- one of few pages that do not require any authentication.

I am using promises to:

1. check if the visitor is already authenticated
2. if they are not, try and anonymously authenticate them
3. if they are authenticated successfully, resolve the promise (and route)
4. if the authentication fails for some reason, reject the promise

Question:

The promise always seems to be rejected the first time a visitor navigates to a page (route) that requires authentication, even when the visitor has been anonymously authenticated successfully (in step 2 above); why would this be happening?

Below I have included my code, and added a comment to highlight the section that seems to be causing the problem.

Thanks for your help with this, it is always appreciated!

```
var app = angular.module('vo2App', ['firebase', 'ngCookies', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/views/home.html'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/views/login.html'
  })
  .when('/oops', {
    controller: 'OopsCtrl',
    resolve: {
      currentAuth: function (){
        return null;
      }
    },
    templateUrl: '/views/oops.html'
  });
}]);

app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', 'Auth', 'ErrorMsg', function ($location, $rootScope, Auth, ErrorMsg) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, next, prev, error) {
    if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
      ErrorMsg.add('Unauthorized');
      // TODO: Make all error messages constants

      $location.url('/oops');
    }
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
    if (! ('resolve' in next)) {
      next.resolve = {};
    }

    if (! ('currentAuth' in next.resolve)) {
      next.resolve.currentAuth = function ($q, Auth) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Auth.$requireAuth().then(deferred.resolve, function () {

          /* ** The following line seems to be causing the problem ** */

          Auth.$authAnonymously().then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED'));
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      };
    }
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`deferred.reject` is not passed to `then` as error function, it is called every time.

```
Auth.$authAnonymously().then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED'));
```

That's why `deferred.promise` is always rejected.

And you should possibly know that the code above is usually referred to as [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern). It is preferable to use existing promises instead of creating a new one with `defer()`.

Comment: Thank you! i was just about to answer my own question now I had figured it out, but you beat me to it, and added the neat little tip!

Comment: The `rootChangeStart` expression may be as simple as `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
  next.resolve = next.resolve || {};
  next.resolve.currentAuth = next.resolve.currentAuth || Auth.$requireAuth.bind(Auth);
 });`. The `.bind(Auth)` may of may not be necessary.